# CSS3 animated desaturation

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I'm using desaturation on an image to make it black and white. I want it to fade back into color on hover (using CSS3 transitions) but I can't seem to get this to work. Any ideas?

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sChY5/ and below is my css

```
img.desaturate {
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
filter: grayscale(100%);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%); -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale');
filter: gray;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}

img.desaturate:hover {
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put the `transition` properties on the good class selector.

Must not be on `img.desaturate:hover`, but on `img.desaturate`

(I talk about your jsfiddle demo, which is not the same code you have posted here)

Comment: I have updated here http://jsfiddle.net/4tshM/ with the transition on the default state. Just checked in Chrome and it works fine but not in Firefox 18.0.2 strangely...

Comment: Gah. Sorted than. Thanks guys 
=====EDIT=======
Actually, not sorted. The filter effect works in FF, it's the transition that isn't working...

Comment: It won't transition because the browser can't interpolate an SVG filter animation, which is what FF is falling back to on hover. You don't need that fallback for the current version of FF though. Just use `filter: grayscale(0)` like here: http://jsfiddle.net/4tshM/8/

Answer (score 0):

I just check it and got it work in jsfiddle as you i think or what you want please clarify.

Comment: If you look well, in jsFiddle, transition is OK when hovering, but not when mouse out (no transition).

Comment: On Firefox, it does desaturate the image and removes the desaturation on hover, but the transition doesn't work. It should take 1 second to remove the desaturation. http://jsfiddle.net/4tshM/1/